# Compact 1-manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, compact-manifolds

I want to find all compact 1-manifolds.

I think these will be lines, with fixed endpoints, and also the case where the endpoints meet.

Hence I think all compact 1-manifolds are homeomorphic

to the closed interval $[a,b]$ or the circle $S^1$.

I am mot sure how to state this in a convincing way.

Comment: You could define an ordering on $M$ by patching the order you have locally in the right way and then use that $M$ is second countable. You also need that $M$ is connected, otherwise $M$ could be isomorphic to a finite disjoint union of $S^1$ and $[0,1]$.